# receive 10002 error from paypal doDirectPaymentMethod

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

i send a request http://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp/ but i receive the 10002 error and my api signature and username and password is true
the invoice number is 10 digit number that is created in random C#.
my code is :

```
string strNVP = "METHOD=DoDirectPayment" +
                    "&VERSION=" + ApiVersion +
                    "&PWD=" + ApiPassword +
                    "&USER=" + ApiUsername +
                    "&SIGNATURE=" + ApiSignature +
                    "&PAYMENTACTION=Sale" +
                    "&IPADDRESS=151.243.189.92" +
                    "&RETURNFMFDETAILS=0" +
                    "&CREDITCARDTYPE=" + creditCard.type +
                    "&ACCT=" + creditCard.number +
                    "&EXPDATE=" + expirationMonth + "20" + expirationYear +
                    "&CVV2=" + creditCard.cvv2 +
                    "&STARTDATE=" +
                    "&ISSUENUMBER=" +
                    "&EMAIL=MatinF@outlook.com" +
                    //the following  represents the billing details
                    "&FIRSTNAME=" + billingFirstName +
                    "&LASTNAME=" + billingLastName +
                    "&STREET=" + billingAddress1 +
                    "&STREET2=" + "" +
                    "&CITY=" + Address[8].ToString() +
                    "&STATE=" + stateName +
                    "&COUNTRYCODE=SW" +
                    "&ZIP=" + Address[5].ToString() +
                    "&AMT=" + TotalPrice +//orderdetails.GrandTotal.ToString("0.0")+
                    "&CURRENCYCODE=SEK" +
                    "&DESC=Test Sale Tickets" +
                    "&INVNUM=" + InvoiceNumber;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this appears to be a limit issue based on the recipient, [version 122 for doDirect APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/?mark=10002) update.

(10002) You've exceeded the receiving limit. This transaction can't be completed

[Click here for more info](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Limits-and-verification/The-recipient-has-exceeded-the-receiving-limit-and-must-provide/td-p/881535?profile.language=en-gb)